# Converting an img tag to a div tag giving odd height results

Tags: html, css

I'm certainly no CSS guru, but I am working on a problem where I'd like to make copying of images just slightly more burdensome for users. Sure, they can still easily be retrieved, but this makes it so you can't just drag/drop them on your desktop. Basically, I had a bunch of markup like this:

```
<img width="400" src="my image.png" class="foo" alt="foo">
```

Instead, I decided to put this into a background image and change the element to a div:

```
<div width="400" class="foo">
```

The problem I have is that the images have a fixed width, but a variable height. This worked excellent when I was using an img tag. It doesn't have the same behavior when I use a div tag. Instead, the CSS is requiring me to force a height property to display anything at all:

This doesn't work

```
.foo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: url(myimage.png);
  /* height: 200px; */
}
```

This sorta does:

```
.foo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: url(myimage.png);
  height: 200px; 
}
```

The problem is the height for the images are all variable as I mentioned before. So it tiles over and over if I hard code a size. The container can be a placeholder for well over 5,000 images, so setting it by hand won't do it. If I can get this div to behave exactly like the img tag did, the problem is solved.

Comment: Please don't do this. By putting the images in CSS background property you make them inaccessible to screen reader users.

Comment: Sure, I'll try a different methodology. I still think that this getting voted down though is silly. It's not opinionated and is a sincere, technical question that should have a home on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *just* trying to prevent people from clicking and drag/dropping, I would say put each `img` into it's own `div` with `position: relative`.  Add another `div` inside that relative `div` that has the following style:

```
div.img_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
    z-index: 9999; /* or anything higher than your img's z-index */
}
```

That will cover up the image with a transparent `div`.

That way the image (which is part of your content) is still syntactically correct in the html.

Everybody is of course correct in saying that they have already downloaded the images to their computers just by visiting the site.

Comment: I think this is the best solution if you really want to prevent drag-and-drop, or even right-click+save. However, I agree with everyone that has mentioned that you can't stop your users from downloading the image. As long as it's being sent to the client, the user can retrieve it. Another point worth mentioning is that you should ensure the extra div's `z-index` is higher than that of the image's, and also that the div should be transparent.

Comment: @Zhihao I figured I would just get him on the right track, but I fleshed it out a bit per your suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: I only meant that as an aside, not a suggestion - your answer was good as it is. :) That being said, you bring up a good point in your answer - using image tags are also better for web semantics and are friendlier towards web crawlers and bots.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to prevent users from reusing your content easily, some good methods are to:
1. Use images with lower resolution to limit reuse potential
2. Watermark your images
3. A combination of both, in an image sprite.

Hacking at it will just be ugly, ineffective, and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting the background of the div, you aren't adding an image to the div.  The div can be resized to whatever it won't resize to what it's background image is.  Just use the  tag.

Comment: Okay I understand what you're saying, but can you possibly give more insight into a solution I can use?

Comment: The point is to use the img tag like you were doing when it worked perfectly.  You aren't going to stop users from "stealing images" that you put on the internet.  Hell they can just pull them right out of their cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you could do with CSS is add a height which would work for all images.  So if you're images range from 200-250px in height, set the div to 250px.  Otherwise, you'll need javascript or server-side scripting to determine the height of the image and set the the CSS.